# Using redirections into promises chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using promises to call a serie of webservices, but I'd like, in some cases, use redirection in the middle of my logic. The problem is that the promises chain continue to execute after the redirection occured.

Here is the code:

```
myfunc = function() {
  return PromiseCall1()

  .then(function(data){
    if (condition){
      $location.path(some_url); // This is a redirection with AngularJS

    } else {
      return PromiseCall2();
    }
  })

  .then(function(data){
    return PromiseCall3();
  })

  .then(function(data){
    // Some other stuff here
  })

};
```

The expected behaviour would be:

- `PromiseCall1()` must be called
- if `condition` is true, no other promise must be called, just do the redirection
- if `condition` is false, Promise2 then Promise3 must be called.

How would you do it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would create another promise object in the myFunc scope. And in every chain check if it is not resolved then continue execution, if resolved than just return from your "then" handler. And when you redirect you can just resolve the promise which will make all the then handlers return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func = function () {
    return PromiseCall1().then(function (data) {
        if (condition) {
            $location.path(some_url); // This is a redirection with AngularJS
        } else {
            return PromiseCall2().then(function (data) {
                return PromiseCall3();
            }).then(function (data) {
                // Some other stuff here
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Yep, from my findings this approach is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Petka's solution is ok. If you want. It is possible if you wrap your then handlers with Maybe.

Something like:

```
var maybe = function(fn){
     return function(value){
          if(value === maybe.Nothing) return maybe.Nothing;
          return fn.apply(this,arguments);
     };
});
maybe.Nothing = {}; // unique reference
```

Which would let you do

```
Promise.try(function(){
    return 15;
}).then(maybe(function(val){
    console.log("got",val);    
    return maybe.Nothing;
})).then(maybe(function(val){
    console.log("This never gets called");  
}));
```

This gives you an explicit value hook to signal not continuing any promise in the chain that is wrapped with a maybe.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. I'll take a look when my understanding of promises will be better.